# Using sum when grouping one more columns in LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by, sum, grouping

I have 2 tables like below.

For comments to vote

```
VoteId      VoteValue  UserId CommentId DateAdded
1              1          1      1      10/11/2013 
2              1          5      1      10/14/2013
3              1          9      2      09/08/2013
4              1          11     3      01/03/2014
```

For users that take point values

```
PointId      Date        PointValue UserId
 1        10/11/2013      1         1     
 2        10/14/2013      1         5
 3        09/08/2013      1         9
 4        01/03/2014      1         11
```

I should find 10 users that most taken votes each month in all comments. Firstly I try to write LINQ like that;

```
    var object = (db.Comments.
Where(c => c.ApplicationUser.Id == comment.ApplicationUser.Id).
FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

I can't use sum and add points to my table. Any helps?
I hope it's clear.

Comment: Your query finds the first comment written by a particular user. What are you trying to do instead?

Comment: I can't top 10 users that taken max point each month..

Comment: You're trying to find the top 10 users by points? What are points, and how are they different from votes?

Comment: Yes, exactly by points. Point is just 1 value, I try to save vote values in Point tables.

Comment: So a point is the total sum of a user's sum of vote values? Have you tried `(from u in db.Users orderby u.Comments.Sum(c => c.VoteValue)).Take(10)`?

Comment: A class diagram would help. The relations between users, votes and point can only be guessed now. And the role of these point values in your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should extract mounth from datetime value, then group by month descending and also take sum of all coments and use Take(10) at the end.